# Combining my first Account with my second

Tags: support

I responded to a few questions before I'd "registered" then, when I registered on a different day it wouldn't let me use my own ID.  How can I combine myself with myself?  Same email was used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only moderators can combine the "anonymous" account with the registered one.

I found [an answer](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/5468/109) by you that you edited with the second profile. I will merge these two for you now.

Comment: That really helps.  Thanks so much.  I guess I should have put "bug"? as a tag.  I'm learning.

Comment: @balancedmama: No, "support" is fine. But don't sweat it - we see all new questions anyway. You can also reach moderators in the [chat] if you like. The chat remembers what's been said even when others aren't present, so nothing gets lost.